# jquery like class selector and using $(this) in pure js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to make a js class selector like in jquery.

```
$('.someClass').click(function(){
    alert($(this).value());
});
```

I have tried in javascript .

```
function myFunction(this){
    alert(this).value;
}
document.getElementsByClassName('someClass').onclick = "myFunction";
```

this isnt working for me and I have also refered to many other forums in stack overflow.

THIS IS NOT DUPLICATE ... IF YOU FIND IT PLEASE HELP ME WITH THE LINK

Comment: alert(this).value; should be alert(this.value);

Comment: `getelementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, which is not a single element, so the attempt to use `.onclick` on it, as if it is a single element, in incorrect.  You would have to loop over them and apply the onclick.  Also, the assignment of the `onclick` should be just `myFunction`, and not a string.  Alternatively you would need to consider using the `addEventListener()` method to set it, rather than the property.  And then your method has the issue of the `.value` being on the alert, and not the `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `querySelectorAll` to get all elements with that class, then use a `forEach` to loop through them and add an event listener to each:

Coded using jQuery:

```js
$('.someClass').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="someClass">Hello, World!</span>
<span class="someClass">1, 2!</span>
<span class="someClass">3, 4!</span>
```

Coded with pure JS:

```js
var all = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass');

all.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(e.innerText);
  })
});
```

```html
<span class="someClass">Hello, World!</span>
<span class="someClass">1, 2!</span>
<span class="someClass">3, 4!</span>
```

Comment: Note that this isn't quite identical. The jQuery sample works on every instance of `.someClass` in the DOM, whereas your plain JS version will only work on the first

Comment: Thats is my whole point.. people are downvoting my question. I just need to know How to make it like jquery. This is not duplicate either.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan True, I changed it to `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @MrGeek  Even querySelector isnt working.. its just providing me the first result.

Comment: @user9514246 I changed it, it's querySelectorAll now, and I'm using a `forEach` loop, check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a tonn buddy that worked..

Comment: @user9514246 You're welcome.